# Jest process quit before all tests execution without any feedback

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, automated-tests, ts-jest

I am very new to Jest, so I'm trying to run my tests serially using the command `yarn jest test -i` (same for `yarn jest test --runInBand` according to Jest documentation).

This is my test files tree:

```
❯ cd src/test 
vipires in scheduling-engine-test/src/test on master 
❯ tree
.
├── customer
│   └── clean.test.ts
├── engine
│   └── job.test.ts
└── schedule
    ├── create.test.ts
    └── generateSchedules.test.ts

3 directories, 4 files
```

The issue is that my project has 4 test files which only one is being tested when I run this command above, it quits occasionally after the first file such as `generateSchedules.test.ts`

The reason why I need to do it serially is that I'm using Jest for integration tests against an REST API and querying an Oracle Database, so when I run just the command `yarn jest test`, jest triggers some workers and run all the tests in parallell. It result in some assertion problems because every test file has an beforeAll() and afterAll() methods that delete all my test data generated during test execution.

Below it is my terminal log output for the command I´ve told:

```
❯ yarn jest test --runInBand
  knex:query update "ENGINE_TASK" set "DAT_EXECUTION" = :1 where "IDT_ENGINE_TASK" in (:2, :3, :4, :5, :6) trx1 +0ms
  knex:query update "TASK" set "DAT_EXECUTION" = :1 where "IDT_TASK" in (:2, :3, :4, :5, :6) trx1 +63ms
  knex:query select * from "ENGINE_TASK" where "IDT_ENGINE_TASK" in (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5) trx3 +165ms
  knex:query delete from "ENGINE_TASK" where "IDT_CUSTOMER_ID" = :1 trx5 +6s
  knex:query delete from "TASK" "T" where exists (select * from "SCHEDULE" "S" where "IDT_CUSTOMER_ID" = :1 and t.idt_schedule = s.idt_schedule) trx5 +55ms
  knex:query delete from "CUSTOMER_EXECUTION_FLAGS" where "IDT_CUSTOMER_ID" = :1 trx5 +70ms
  knex:query delete from "SCHEDULE" "S" where "IDT_CUSTOMER_ID" = :1 trx5 +50ms
 PASS  src/test/schedule/generateSchedules.test.ts (15.647 s)
  ✓ generate schedules for today (8644 ms)
  ✓ should block delete on scheduled task (2464 ms)
  ✓ should permit delete on scheduled task (3173 ms)


 RUNS  src/test/engine/job.test.ts
vipires in scheduling-engine-test on master took 21s
```

Notice that the last log line from Jest was `RUNS  src/test/engine/job.test.ts` and then the following line is from my terminal again informing that the execution took 21 seconds.

It was very hard to me to explain that behavior since I wasn't able to find any occurrence of this problem before at Jest documentation nor Stackoverflow. I've tried to discourse about the execution in way to make this post shorten, but anyway if more code is needed to investigate this behavior just let me know.

Node and OS info:

- Node version: v14.16.1
- Yarn version: v2.4.1
- Jest version: 26.6.2
- Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier:   MacBookPro 11,4
  Processor Name:   Quad-Core Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2,2 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    4
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 6 MB
  Hyper-Threading Technology:   Enabled
  Memory:   16 GB
  Boot ROM Version: 199.0.0.0.0
  SMC Version (system): 2.29f24

Comment: I see references to 'knex' and what looks like SQL queries, so I assume underneath you are using the [node-oracledb module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb).  If so, see the report at https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1369

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And yes, I'm using knex in this project do query an Oracle Database and update some lines whitin my tests.. I'm goin' to check this issue evolving the oracledb and jest, but my coworker is using a Linux Ubuntu 18.04 and he can run all the tests with the --runInBand flag option without any side problems